# Peculiar similarity

Tags: power-series

I am an experimental physicist and have a math question.
There are two functions, one being

$-1/\log(x)$

the other

$\sqrt{x}/(1-x)$

which are remarkably similar in the domain ]0,1[.

Does anybody have an idea why?

Comment: In what sense are they similar? The first one tends to $0$ slower than  the second one as $x \to 0$.

Comment: Did you intentionally put a $-1$ in your $log$ equation? They seem to be more similar is it was $1$ instead of $-1$

Comment: Ah, I am sorry. The values are very similar! See here: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+-1%2Flog%28x%29+and+sqrt%28x%29%2F%281-x%29+from+0+to+1

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out myself.
Develop $\log(x)$ around 1, then write out $-\frac{1}{\log(x)}$, factor out (1-x) and then write $\sqrt(x)$ as $1/1/\sqrt(x)$ and develop $1/\sqrt(x)$ around 1, then compare.

Answer (score 1):

The approximation $\ln x\approx x-1$ shows these functions are similar when $x$ is close to $1$. When $x$ is small and positive, so are both functions. But they look [less similar](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+-1%2Flog%28x%29+and+sqrt%28x%29%2F%281-x%29+from+0+to+0.1) if you zoom to say $0\le x\le 0.1$, and [even less similar](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+-1%2Flog%28x%29+and+sqrt%28x%29%2F%281-x%29+from+0+to+0.001) if you zoom to $0\le x\le 0.001$. Indeed,$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\sqrt{x}/(1-x)}{-1/\ln x}=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{-2\sqrt{x}\ln\sqrt{x}}{1-x}=-2\lim_{y\to^+}y\ln y=0.$$

Comment: True, I did not notice that! But for my application, x is 1-losses, and I want to decrease losses, so I expect x to be closer to one. It is however strange that the functions are not be exactly the same, since both ways of calculating them should be equivalent!

Comment: @DanielR. Are you saying you solved some problem in two ways, and they gave those two functions, and you want to make sense of the answers differing? If so, maybe you should ask another question about that.

Comment: Originally, I wanted a formal way to show they are the same, or at least explain the similarity for that large part of the interval I am interested in. Now, I am thinking about what you said last: Work out why they differ.

Comment: @DanielR. Well, as I said, they're both roughly $1/(1-x)$ if $x\approx1$, but if $x\ll1$ one function is much smaller than the other. How did you come across them, exactly?

Comment: I was calculating the finesse of a ring resonator using the phase response function.

Comment: @DanielR. Ah, well, as I said, you may need to ask a question about why calculations differed.

Answer (score 1):

The series development around $x=1$ gives:
$$
\eqalign{
  & {{\sqrt {\left( {1 + x} \right)} } \over {\left( {1 - \left( {1 + x} \right)} \right)}}
 =  - {{\sqrt {\left( {1 + x} \right)} } \over x} =  - \left( {{1 \over x} + {1 \over 2} - {x \over 8} + {{x^{\,2} } \over {16}} + O\left( {x^{\,3} } \right)} \right)  \cr 
  &  - {1 \over {\ln \left( {1 + x} \right)}} =  - \left( {{1 \over x} + {1 \over 2} - {x \over {12}} + {{x^{\,2} } \over {24}} + O\left( {x^{\,3} } \right)} \right) \cr} 
$$